# Find frequent itemsets

Tags: algorithm, data-analysis

I have a following dataset:
[image]

Where `|` splits sets. Basically, for example row number 2 looks like this:

```
{{null}, {shop, atm}, {null}, {shop, atm}, {null}, {null}}
```

The order of the set does not play any role: `{shop, amt} == {atm, shop}`.

What I want to do two things:

1) find common patterns and frequent itemsets. For example, set {shop, atm} is frequent as row it is present in rows 1, 2 and 4.

2) Figure out what sets (or set elements) are followed by which elements. For example, shop is very often followed by other shop: `{shop, atm}, {shop}` - row 1 and {shop}, {shop, atm} - row 4.

First problem can be easily solved with Apriori algorithm, right? That is pretty easy. But how about the second problem? How can I solve it? Which algorithms to user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Apriori will find frequent item sets (i.e., sets with a high support count). FP-Tree is often better since it only requires two passes through the data.

The second part, rule generation, involves taking pairs of frequent itemsets where the first is a superset of the second. You can then form a rule where the smaller set is the antecedent and the difference of the sets is the consequent. The ratio of the support counts of larger itemset to the smaller is the statistical confidence of the rule.

This is all fairly basic data mining stuff, and is well described in Wikipedia, etc. Packages such as Weka and R do the hard work for you.